# HTML5 websockets vs PHP websockets vs node.js websockets?

Tags: php, html, node.js

I have decided to use WebSockets for my website chat application and I have just started to learn websockets, but I have three different options, node.js , PHP or HTML5.

What I want to know that is there any difference between the three, I mean I don't want to learn all the three if any one is better than the others.

Comment: Everybody uses https://socket.io/
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Web Sockets is a *protocol* which defines how two parties can communicate. It's language agnostic; any language can provide an adapter to talk to another web socket. The three things you mention are three different implementations for of this adapter. For a chat application, you'll likely need at least two of them: one server, one client. Choose which language you'd like to write your server in (PHP or Node.js) and use the HTML 5 web sockets feature in the browser to talk to the server.

Comment: OK. It means that I have to make choice for server as well as client and need to learn HTML5 (for client) and PHP (for server) websocket implementation. Right?

Comment: Yep, pretty much. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

**What are websockets:**

> WebSockets represent a standard for bi-directional realtime
>   communication between servers and clients. between any server and any
>   client.

A WebSocket server can be written in any server-side programming language that is capable of Berkeley sockets, such as PHP or Node.

So like any other protocol, lets say like http: you will need a client and a server.

As already mentioned, server side implementations for web-sockets can be done using any one of the server side languages, including PHP and Node.

And for the client side implementation you will need html5 we-bsockets, which run on the browser.

> **So of-cource you will not need to learn both PHP and Node at the same
>   time, but one of these plus html5.**

I would recommend using NodeJS for implementing sockets, as it will let you use same technology(JavaScript) on both client and server. There is `socket.io` module for nodeJS which  will take care of both server-side and client-side components with similar APIs.

So you will not require to write too much of code for implementing sockets. here is an example with node:

**Server:**

```
var server = require("net").createServer();
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

var handleClient = function (socket) {
    // we've got a client connection
    socket.emit("tweet", {user: "nodesource", text: "Hello, world!"});
};

io.on("connection", handleClient);

server.listen(8080);
```

**Client:**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost");
</script>


socket.on("connect", function () {
    console.log("Connected!");
});
```

**Note:**

web-sockets for client side is html5 feature, and not availbale in browsers which don't support html5. You can see the browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=Web%20Sockets)

**If you still choose PHP you can learn about HTML5 websockets [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)**